# gawk regex to find any record having characters other then the specified by character class in regex pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, gawk

I have list of email addresses in a text file. I have a pattern having character classes that specifies what characters are allowed in the email addresses. 
Now from that input file, I want to only search the email addresses that has the characters other than the allowed ones. 
I am trying to write a gawk for the same, but not able to get it to work properly.
Here is the gawk that I am trying:

```
gawk -F "," ' $2!~/[[:alnum:]@\.]]/ { print "has invalid chars" }' emails.csv
```

The problem I am facing is that the above gawk command only matches the records that has NONE of the alphanumeric, @ and . (dot) in them. But what I am looking for is the records that are having the allowed characters but along with them the not-allowed ones as well.

For example, the above command would find

> "_-()&*(*()%"

as the above only has the characters not in regex pattern, but will not find

> "abc-123@xyz,com"

. as it also has the characters that are present in specified character classes in regex pattern.

Comment: this question would benefit from a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

How about several tests together: contains an alnum and an @ and a dot and an invalid character

```awk
$2 ~ /[[:alnum:]]/ && $2 ~ /@/ && $2 ~ /\./ && $2 ~ /[^[:alnum:]@.]/
```

Comment: `code` $2 ~ /[[:alnum:]@\.]/ && $2 ~ /[^[:alnum:]@\.]/ `code`

Comment: Problem with that is it will match a line like `@+` because you're looking for *one of* alnum or @ or dot. My suggestion enforces *all of* those three

Comment: matching all 3 of those wouldn't get you much closer to validating an email address though, `.7@`, for example would pass the test, so YMMV to the benefits of testing all 3 vs `/[[:alnum:@.]/`. `$2 ~ /[[:alnum:]].*@.*\./` would be better but still leaves a lot of holes.

Comment: @iamharish15 as mentioned elsethread you do not need to escape `.` within a bracket expression and testing a regexp and then the negation of that regexp is just another form of code duplication which is always a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong here:

```
/[[:alnum:]@\.]]/
```

It should be:

```
/[[:alnum:]@.]/
```

Not removal of an extra `]` fron end.

**Test Case:**

```
# regex with extra ]
awk -F "," '{print ($2 !~ /[[:alnum:]@.]]/)}' <<< 'abc,ab@email.com'
1

# correct regex
awk -F "," '{print ($2 !~ /[[:alnum:]@.]/)}' <<< 'abc,ab@email.com'
0
```

Comment: No, actually, that extra bracket was by mistake. But for your test case, even with the correct email address, it matches the pattern.

Comment: No that's not correct. `awk -F "," ' $2 !~ /[[:alnum:]@.]/ { print "has invalid chars" }' <<< 'abc,ab@email.com'` will output that message. But first one with extra `]` won't work.

Comment: Also see my updated answer with different results with an extra `]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care whether the string has a valid character? If not (and it seems like you don't), the simple solution is

```
$2 ~ /[^[:alnum:]@.]/{ print "has invalid chars" }
```

That won't trigger on an empty string, so you might want to add a test for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your question would REALLY benefit from some concise, testable sample input and expected output as right now we're all guessing at what you want but maybe this does it?

```
awk -F, '{r=$2} gsub(/[[:alnum:]@.]/,"",r) && (r!="") { print "has invalid chars" }' emails.csv
```

e.g. using the 2 input examples you provided:

```
$ cat file
_-()&(()%
abc-123@xyz,com

$ awk '{r=$0} gsub(/[[:alnum:]@.]/,"",r) && (r!="") { print $0, "has invalid chars" }' file
abc-123@xyz,com has invalid chars
```

There are more accurate email regexps btw, e.g.:

```
\<[[:alnum:]._%+-]+@[[:alnum:]_.-]+\.[[:alpha:]]{2,}\>
```

which is a gawk-specific (for word delimiters `\<` and `\>`) modification of the one described at http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html after updating to use POSIX character classes.

If you are trying to validate email addresses do not use the regexp you started with as it will declare `@` and `7` to each be valid email addresses.

See also [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/1745001) for more email regexp details.